# How to compute the determinant of some 3x3 matrix more quickly than by Sarrus method?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I know that the determinant of this matrix: $ \begin{bmatrix} 2-\lambda & -1 & 1\\1& 5-\lambda & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2-\lambda \end{bmatrix} $ is $(3-\lambda)^3$ by simply computing the determinant (using Sarrus method), but I want to know if I can compute this determinant faster, by doing some operations with the rows and columns.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Replace $C_3$ by $C_3+C_2$, factor $3-\lambda$ in $C_3$, replace $C_2$ by $C_2-C_1-C_3$, factor $3-\lambda$ in $C_2$, replace $C_1$ by $C_1-C_2$, observe that the resulting matrix is upper triangular with diagonal $(3-\lambda,1,1)$, qed.

Comment: @Did Please add this as answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $3 \times 3$ Matrices, Sarrus is the fastest way to go. You might find matrices that have certain features (a coloumn or a row with no or only one nonzero element), which can give you a boost, but in general (as in this case), you should use Sarrus.

---

Example where you can go faster using Laplace's formula:
$$M=\begin{bmatrix} 2-\lambda & -1 & 1\\0& 5-\lambda & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2-\lambda \end{bmatrix}$$

As you can see, this is very similar to your matrix, but the first row has only one element different from zero ($2-\lambda$). *If this is not the case, Laplace's won't save you work on $3\times 3$ or smaller.*

So we go down the first row with Laplace:

\begin{align}
\det(M) &= \det\begin{pmatrix} 2-\lambda & -1 & 1\\0& 5-\lambda & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2-\lambda \end{pmatrix}\\
 &= (2-\lambda) \cdot \det\begin{pmatrix} 5-\lambda & -2 \\ 1 & 2-\lambda \end{pmatrix}
-0  \cdot \det\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1\\1 & 2-\lambda \end{pmatrix}
+0  \cdot \det\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1\\5-\lambda & -2 \end{pmatrix}\\
&=(2-\lambda) \cdot \det\begin{pmatrix} 5-\lambda & -2 \\ 1 & 2-\lambda \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

... and this is much easier to calculate.

For more detail, look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace.27s_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix).

Comment: Thank you Kaligule, I tried to make some operations with the rows and/or the columns, but I was unable to compute this determinant, using this method. I was able to compute the determinant using Sarrus.